# Scroll Form to Top of Window and Focus on First Input Field

Tags: javascript, html

We have a "Let's talk" link in the header:

```
<div class="letstalk">
<a href="javascript:scrollForm();">
Let's talk <img src="/wp-content/uploads/link-icon.png">
</a>
</div>
```

When the user clicks this link, the scrollForm script:

```
<script>
function scrollForm()
{
   document.getElementById('input_1_1').focus()
}
</script>
```

Focuses on the first input field of the form and scrolls the form into view, however, the scroll position is inconstant between browsers, how can I force the script to scroll so that id="formcontainer" is at the top of the window? While still applying the focus to the first input field. Everything I've tried seems to only do one of these two things.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```js
document.myForm.scrollIntoView();
document.myForm.desiredInput.focus();
```